# Creating a "Repeat last macro" keybinding in sublime text vintage mode

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

At the moment, I am trying out sublime text. Most of it is fine, but there is one big feature that I can't figure out how to implement in sublime text. In vim, have have space bound to repeat the last macro that I performed. However, I can't find a good way to implement it in sublime text.

In an effort to learn more, I looked at the macro key bindings in the vintage package:

```
{ "keys": ["q"], "command": "vi_end_record_macro",
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}, {"key": "is_recording_macro"}]
},

{ "keys": ["@", "<character>"], "command": "vi_replay_macro",
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```

And (what I think) is the relevant class in the actual plugin:

```
class ViReplayMacro(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, character):
```

What I am unable to figure out is how to remember what the last command was, and failing that just have space call the vi macro recorded on 'q'. This means I need to bind vi_replay_macro(q) to space, but I don't understand how the key binding passes which character to replay to the command.

EDIT: I created [a plugin](https://github.com/roglew/sublime-repeat-vi-macro) that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have to write your own plugin to run the last macro run. You can try using the `command_history` method, then search backwards till you find a `vi_replay_macro` or `run_macro` command. I'm just making a guess though based on what I know about ST, so there could be other ways to go about it.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I created a [quick plugin](https://github.com/roglew/sublime-repeat-vi-macro) that does the job