# Sublime Text 2 mac in vintage mode: recorded macro only works once

Tags: sublimetext2

I use q to record macro to 1 then use `@1` to invoke the macro. The macro basically works once and after that `@1` does nothing.

However, even when `@1` is not working, I can still use the default hotkey `ctrl+shift+q` to replay the macro.

Comment: Are you asking why @1 only works once?

Comment: I cannot use "@" to replay macro at all in ST3... Maybe you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327580/creating-a-repeat-last-macro-keybinding-in-sublime-text-vintage-mode for some info?